# Java cast child to parent

Tags: java

Class Lion extends Animal.

Here is my code:

```
Animal a = new Animal();
Lion b = new Lion();
Animal c = (Animal) b;

Animal[] arr = { a, b, c };

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i].getClass().getName());
    arr[i].run();
}
```

The result is:

> test2.Animal
>
> Animal Run...
>
> test2.Lion
>
> Lion Run...
>
> test2.Lion
>
> Lion Run...

From the example seems that "c" is a "Lion", not an "Animal". Why is that happening?

Comment: Perhaps this question may help you understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049580/what-is-the-difference-between-typecasting-and-typeconversion-in-c-or-java

Comment: This is called "polimorphism"

Answer (score 11):

> From the example seems that "c" is a "Lion", not an "Animal". Why is that happening?

Because `c` **is** a Lion:

```
Lion b = new Lion();   // Creates a Lion
Animal c = (Animal) b; // Refers to the Lion through an Animal variable
```

Now, `c` is an `Animal`-typed reference to a `Lion` object. The object is still a `Lion`, it's just the reference to it is limited to `Animal` stuff. So when you ask that object what its class is (not what your *interface* to it is in the `c` variable / third entry in your array), it tells you it's a `Lion`.

This is exactly like this situation:

```
Map m = new HashMap();
```

The `m` reference is typed `Map` and so you can only use it to access the things the `Map` interface defines, but the *object* it's referring to is a `HashMap` instance.

Comment: Hello, could you explain how can the reference Lion object be recovered even tho it has been casted to animal? In C++ this would cause pruning of all the fields in Lion that are not in Animal.

Comment: @Vallerious - Java and C++ use quite different semantics. Java's object variables are references to the object rather than directly containing the object, so they're much more like C++ pointers. (Caveat: I haven't done any real C++ in ~22 years.)  In the above, Java's `Lion b` is like C++'s `Lion *b`. `b` *points to* the object rather than directly containing it. So `Animal c = (Animal);` in Java is like `Animal *c = (Animal*)b;` in C++, it's just pointing a second variable at the same object.

Comment: @Vallerious - FWIW, [this Java code](https://ideone.com/M4kSnA) is similar to [this C++ code](https://ideone.com/Lg2ZdS) (again, caveat, my C++ is really rusty).

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. I checked and indeed slicing happens when you use Animal a = lion, I guess the assignment operator does not copy fields to the Animal because it cannot be implemented to do so.

Comment: @Vallerious - I'm not sure whether you're quoting Java or C++ code in that comment...? In Java, `Animal a = lion;` makes both `a` and `lion` refer to the same object (which still has all of its fields; those fields aren't directly accessible through `a` because of its type, but you can still get them with casting).

Comment: I meant C++. So Java and C++ are similar in that regard, just Java hides the pointer syntax for us. :)

Comment: @Vallerious - Pretty much, yeah. :-)

Answer (score 3):

A cast doesn't make the referenced object change its type, it just restricts itself to the methods of the supertype. You couldn't cast a `Banana` to an `Animal` for these reasons.

The cast in your line

```
Animal c = (Animal) b;
```

happens automatically anyways. You just need to specify your cast when you downcast:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
Dog d = (Dog) a;
```

But both `a` and `d` still point to a `Dog` in the heap and will thus use the instance methods of the `Dog` class if they override the methods of the `Animal` class.
In other words, `a` is a `Dog`, but as long as it is declared as (or typecast to) an `Animal`, it can only use `Animal` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking `getClass`.

Method invocation resolves at runtime, hence it prints `Lion` and not `Animal`.

Answer (score 1):

Your object `c` is a reference to an object, and the object must be of type `Animal` or any sub class. Just because the object reference is `Animal` doesn't guarantee that the object is an `Animal`, it just means that it will behave as an `Animal`, and you can call all of the methods on that class that you want. This is part of Polymorphism.