# Return value pointer syntax

Tags: go

In the following code:

```
type boolValue bool

func newBoolValue(val bool, p *bool) *boolValue {
    *p = val
    return (*boolValue)(p)
}
```

What is the last line doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> Conversions are expressions of the form `T(x`) where `T` is a type and
>   `x` is an expression that can be converted to type `T`.

```
type boolValue bool

func newBoolValue(val bool, p *bool) *boolValue {
    *p = val
    return (*boolValue)(p)
}
```

`(*boolValue)(p)` is doing a type conversion from `*bool`, the type of `p`, to `*boolValue`, the type of the `newBoolValue` function return value. Go requires explicit conversions. The conversion is allowed because `bool` is the underlying type of `boolValue`.

If you simply write `return p` without the conversion the compiler error message explains the problem:

```
return p

error: cannot use p (type *bool) as type *boolValue in return argument
```

Answer (score 1):

It is casting the variable `p` of type `*bool` to type `*boolValue`, in order to match the return argument value. It would throw an error otherwise.

Comment: Technically, it's converting, not casting.  As JimB likes to point out, Go doesn't have type casting, only type conversion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049580/what-is-the-difference-between-typecasting-and-typeconversion-in-c-or-java https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

Answer (score 0):

Type is strict in go. If you see below program which I have crafted it to your change, the Output will be of type `*main.boolValue`. That's why you are type casting `bool` type to `boolValue` type in the return statement.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type boolValue bool

func main() {
    var a bool = true
    b := &a
    rtnVal := newBoolValue(a, b)
    fmt.Println("The type of rtnVal is ", reflect.TypeOf(rtnVal))
}

func newBoolValue(val bool, p *bool) *boolValue {
    *p = val
    return (*boolValue)(p)
}
```

Output:

```
The type of rtnVal is  *main.boolValue
```

Comment: Or, even easier, you could do what the compiler does. Look at the return type in the function declaration. It's `*boolValue` in `package main`. No programming required.