# Where is the definition of unchecked warning for Object to generic type conversion?

Tags: java, generics, type-conversion, warnings, javac

[JLS 5.1.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9) defines the unchecked conversion as follows :

> Let G name a generic type declaration with n type parameters.
>
> There is an unchecked conversion from the raw class or interface type
>   G to any parameterized type of the form `G<T1,...,Tn>`.
>
> There is an unchecked conversion from the raw array type `G[]` to any array type type of the form `G<T1,...,Tn>[]`.
>
> Use of an unchecked conversion causes a compile-time unchecked warning
>   unless `G<...>` is a parameterized type in which all type arguments are
>   unbounded wildcards, or the unchecked warning is suppressed by the
>   SuppressWarnings annotation

As far as I can understand it says that unchecked conversion occurs **if you cast a raw type** to a generic type with bounded type parameters. then why following code generates a unchecked warning:

```
public class DoubleStar{

    public static void print(Object object){
       ((A<String>)object).print();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        print(new Object());
    }
}

class A<T>{
    public void print(){
        System.out.print("HELLO");
    }
}
```

As **Object is not a raw type** (AFAIK) why should the above code generate a unchecked cast warning and where this behaviour is defined ?

Comment: *"Let G name a generic type declaration..."* Object is not a generic type declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong section which is why it doesn't seem to make sense in the context of your example.

The warning you have is an unchecked *cast*. You are looking at the section on unchecked *conversions* ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049580/what-is-the-difference-between-typecasting-and-typeconversion-in-c-or-java)).

[See 5.5.2 "Checked Casts and Unchecked Casts"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.2)

> A cast from a type S to a type T is *statically known to be correct* if and only if S <: T
>   (§4.10).
>
> A cast from a type S to a parameterized type (§4.5) T is unchecked
>   unless at least one of the following conditions holds:
>
> - S <: T
> - All of the type arguments (§4.5.1) of T are unbounded wildcards
> - T <: S and S has no subtype X other than T where the type arguments of
>     X are not contained in the type arguments of T.
>
> A cast from a type S to a type variable T is unchecked unless S <: T.
>
> An unchecked cast from S to T is *completely unchecked* if the cast from
>   |S| to |T| is statically known to be correct. Otherwise, it is
>   *partially unchecked*.
>
> An unchecked cast causes a compile-time unchecked warning, unless
>   suppressed by the SuppressWarnings annotation (§9.6.3.5).
>
> A cast is *checked* if it is not statically known to be correct and it
>   is not unchecked.
>
> If a cast to a reference type is not a compile-time error, there are
>   several cases:
>
> - The cast is statically known to be correct.
>
> No run-time action is performed for such a cast.
>
> - The cast is a completely unchecked cast.
>
> No run-time action is performed for such a cast.
>
> - The cast is a partially unchecked cast.
>
> Such a cast requires a run-time validity check. The check is performed
>   as if the cast had been a checked cast between |S| and |T|, as
>   described below.
>
> - The cast is a checked cast.
>
> Such a cast requires a run-time validity check. If the value at run
>   time is null, then the cast is allowed. Otherwise, let R be the class
>   of the object referred to by the run-time reference value, and let T
>   be the erasure (§4.6) of the type named in the cast operator. A cast
>   conversion must check, at run time, that the class R is assignment
>   compatible with the type T, via the algorithm in §5.5.3.
>
> Note that R cannot be an interface when these rules are first applied
>   for any given cast, but R may be an interface if the rules are applied
>   recursively because the run-time reference value may refer to an array
>   whose element type is an interface type.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you cast an `Object` into an `A<String>` the compiler has no way to check (or to generate the code to check) that the `Object` is indeed an `A<String>` and not an `A<Integer>` (or whatever).